# Is the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem true for infinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, infinite-matrices, stochastic-matrices

The [Birkhoff–von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem&redirect=no) theorem states that every $n \times n$ doubly stochastic matrix is a convex combination of permutation matrices. Is this true for $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ matrices as well? If so, can you provide a reference?

Comment: Late to the party but a reference for this other than the one by bof is the [1960 paper by Kendall on "On Infinite Doubly‐Stochastic Matrices and Birkhoffs Problem 111"](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-35.1.81) - essentially, the statement generalizes to $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ if the convex hull is replaced by the closed convex hull in the weak topology.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the exact answer to your question but I found a reference that should be useful. In L. Mirsky's book *Transversal Theory* (Academic Press, 1971, ISBN 0-12-498550-5), on p.213,
I read:

> Birkhoff's theorem has been extended to infinite d.s. matrices, with the notion of convex closure in a suitable topological vector space replacing that of convex hull. For references to work in this field, see Mirsky (**1**).

The reference Mirsky (**1**) is to the following paper:

> L. Mirsky, Results and problems in the theory of doubly-stochastic matrices,
>   *Z. Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie* **1** (1962–3), 319–334.